# Network Caching on a Split Database

Tags: database, caching, ms-access, split

We're currently developing a survey database. This survey is to be conducted in a lot of different locations, most without wifi or cell service. We are using a Windows 7 Tablet to conduct the survey and a desktop to write the code etc.

I'd like to know if there are any limitations in MS-Access to placing the backend (tables etc) on a network drive and having the front-ends local when the tablet will not always have network connectivity.

I'm sure there's a way to cache the backend to the tablet, that's not the issue; it's **whether or not Ms-Access will accept changes when the cached copy returns with the tablet to the network.** I've been unable to find any literature on this or even if it's possible. I may be wrong about how caching works.

Input?

Comment: MS Access is a file based system, and presumably, there will be no overlaps in data from a survey, so why not assemble and concatenate the back-ends from each tablet?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "assemble and concatenate"?

Comment: We were doing that for a bit, but it's a slightly complicated implementation: the tablets are using the Runtime, the desktop is using full Access. This meant we were copying the info from the tablet tables to the desktop, deleting the tablet's copy and replacing it with the desktop's copy. Then we had to make sure the files were renamed to .accdr etc. It just seemed sloppy, so we split it. We havn't run into issues yet (see 1st comment in Eugen's answer) but they wanted me to move the DB to a network drive. Not manditory, it's working OK now.

Comment: Why are the tablets not working with a front end and back end? Then you are just transferring the be. You probably do not have to replace it. I agree with @Eugene about your data being eaten.

Comment: We only just split the DB, so the above was how we had it running this morning/last week. The problem arises when I need to edit the schema of the tables: with one backend (assuming the tablet is offline) it allows me to edit schema while keeping all of the records as the tablet had them. As seperate, split backends, I'd have to still copy/paste the records into the new schema then replace the backend. I was thinking there may be a simpler way, hence this caching, but now thinking that's a no-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sure as hell running into problems - think of a user leaving WiFi coverage with the application open. Been there, done that, never evergonna do it again.

Use a simple, classic "last change timestamp/user/client" sync pattern - not sexy, but it works.

Comment: Right now we're actually using Dropbox to sync the backend. As we don't need to make changes to the schema, it's working well, and if the dev does make changes, we make sure the Tablet is out of the database. Basically the Dev only needs the backend to help base new features in the front-end. Would this same functionality be available with a network caching system?

Comment: Dropbox will (normally) not eat your .mdb file - leaving WiFi Coverage with the file open might easily do so.